# Using locales in php with type double causing lot's of problems

Tags: php, locale

I wasted some time on finding a bug in doctrine in combination with mysql where a double `2.5` was constantly stored as `2.0`. I found out that using german local `de_DE` the decimal delimiter `,` is used instead of a `.` which caused doctrine to create a sql query like

```
insert into table (doubleColumn) values('2,5') -- will result in a 2.0
```

This issue causing this is reproducible using that lines in php

```
$a=2.5;
printf("%s",$a); // prints out 2.5
echo $a; // prints out 2.5
setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE");
printf("%s",$a); // prints out 2,5
echo $a; // prints out 2,5
echo "my number " . $a; // also results in a 2,5
```

So my question is, why does php use the current locale for transforming types like `double` into a string. Like in Java this is not the case

```
Double a = 2.5;
System.out.println(a.toString()); // prints out 2.5
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
System.out.println(a.toString()); // still prints out 2.5
```

Is there any reason why php is using the current set locale for string conversion?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53711

Comment: mh really troubling, since the entire doctrine project seems to have issues related to that

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean using `printf("%f", $a);` (because your code works fine here).
The answer is located in the docs :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

> f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
>
> F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware). Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.

So you should use `%F`

Comment: But even `echo` is locale aware...!

Comment: uuh... `php -r "setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); echo 2.5;"` works fine and displays `2.5` here.

Comment: Prints 2,5 on my system. Sure you have `de_DE` installed...?

Comment: `echo "my number " . $a;` is also transforming to `2,5` so concatenating a double a string is also locale aware which kinds of troubling me

Comment: Yes I do, and even trying with fr_FR gives the same result.